# Material Design in Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

At the moment I can not find a somewhat up to date version of mdc for dart. I can find for example https://pub.dev/packages/mdc_web and https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components but both are really far away from an up to date implementation of Material Design.

Is there a library apart from this I can use, so that I can use up to date material design with dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two links you posted have different use cases. The former is for vanilla web dev using Dart, and probably your best bet unless you plan to use AngularDart. Even though it has not been updated in over a year, I don't think there is anything newer. You could try cloning the repo and adding support yourself for the missing or outdated components which you desire.

AngularDart is (in my opinion) a great framework. The latter link you posted is specifically for use with AngularDart. Last update it was 15 days ago. This project is maintained by Google and I think it is safe to say that Google is by far the largest user of AngularDart. Their material design components which you linked to are going to be your best bet in this case.

Generally speaking though, using Dart for web dev never achieved widespread adoption, so there are not large communities with a lot of active package maintainers.